# Excel VBA: Run-Time Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I have the following list on Sheet1:

```
   COLUMN A    COLUMNB             COLUMN C 
1  ADDRESS     Services(s) USED    VEHICLE(S) USED
2  Address1    Service1, Service3  Vehicle1, Vehicle3, Vehicle4  
3  Address2    Service1, Service4  Vehicle1, Vehicle3, Vehicle4
4  Address3    Service2, Service5  Vehicle1, Vehicle2, Vehicle5
5  Address4    Service2, Service3  Vehicle1, Vehicle6 
6  Address1    Service5, Service6  Vehicle2, Vehicle5, Vehicle6 
7  Address2    Service2, Service3  Vehicle2, Vehicle3
8  Address4    Service4, Service6  Vehicle1, Vehicle2, Vehicle3, Vehicle4, Vehicle5, Vehicle6
```

On Sheet2, I would like the following output in Column B when I enter "Address1" in cell B4

```
   COLUMN A    COLUMN B            


4              Address1                                                                 

12             Service1
13             Service3
14             Service5
15             Service6
16
17

50             Vehicle1
51             Vehicle2
52             Vehicle3
53             Vehicle4
54             Vehicle5
56             Vehicle6
```

The following is the code I am using:

**Worksheet_Change Code** ("Sheet2" module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' call Function only if modifed cell is in Column "B"
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Range("B4"), Worksheets("Google Data").Range("E1:E" & LastRow(Worksheets("Google Data"))), 0)) Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        If (Target.Value <> "") Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call FilterAddress(Target.Value)
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            MsgBox Target.Address & "Cell can't be blank, Input a value first."
            Err.Clear
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Else
On Error Resume Next
    MsgBox "The Appointment # you entered is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again."
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Sub FilterAddress Code** (Regular module)

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAddress(FilterVal As String)


Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FilterRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim Dict As Object
'Dim ID
Dim Vehicle As Variant
Dim VehicleArr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Service As Variant
Dim ServiceArr As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim My_Range As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in column "A" (Adress)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set FilterRng = .Range("A1:C" & LastRow)

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ' AutoFilter "Sheet1" according to value in "Sheet2" in Column B
    FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterVal

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' create an array with size up to number of rows >> will resize it later
    ReDim ServiceArr(1 To LastRow)
    j = 1 ' init array counter

    For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' read values from cell to array using the Split function
        Service = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        For i = LBound(Service) To UBound(Service)
            Service(i) = Trim(Service(i)) ' remove extra spaces from string

            If Not Dict.exists(Service(i)) Then
                Dict.Add Service(i), Service(i)

                ' save Service Name to array >> will use it later for "Bubble-sort" and paste in "Sheet2"
                ServiceArr(j) = Service(i)
                j = j + 1 ' increment ServiceArr counter
            End If
        Next i

    Next cell
    ' resize array up to number of actual Service
    ReDim Preserve ServiceArr(1 To j - 1)

End With

Dim ServiceTmp As Variant
' Bubble-sort Service Array >> sorts the Service array from smallest to largest
For i = 1 To UBound(ServiceArr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(ServiceArr)
        If ServiceArr(j) < ServiceArr(i) Then
            ServiceTmp = ServiceArr(j)
            ServiceArr(j) = ServiceArr(i)
            ServiceArr(i) = ServiceTmp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' now the "fun" part >> paste to "Sheet2"
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Value = "ADDRESS"
    .Range("B4").Value = FilterVal
    .Range("C1").Value = "VEHICLE(S) USED"

    ' clear contents from previous run

    .Range("B12:B17").ClearContents
    .Range("B12:B" & UBound(ServiceArr) + 11) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ServiceArr)

End With

FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in column "A" (Adress)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set FilterRng = .Range("A1:C" & LastRow)

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ' AutoFilter "Sheet1" according to value in "Sheet2" in Column B
    FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterVal

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' create an array with size up to number of rows >> will resize it later
    ReDim VehicleArr(1 To LastRow)
    y = 1 ' init array counter

    For Each cell In .Range("C2:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' read values from cell to array using the Split function
        Vehicle = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        For x = LBound(Vehicle) To UBound(Vehicle)
            Vehicle(x) = Trim(Vehicle(x)) ' remove extra spaces from string

            If Not Dict.exists(Vehicle(x)) Then
                Dict.Add Vehicle(x), Vehicle(x)

                ' save Vehicle Name to array >> will use it later for "Bubble-sort" and paste in "Sheet2"
                VehicleArr(y) = Vehicle(x)
                y = y + 1 ' increment VehicleArr counter
            End If
        Next x

    Next cell
    ' resize array up to number of actual Vehicle
    ReDim Preserve VehicleArr(1 To y - 1)

End With

Dim VehicleTmp As Variant
' Bubble-sort Vehicle Array >> sorts the Vehicle array from smallest to largest
For x = 1 To UBound(VehicleArr) - 1
    For y = x + 1 To UBound(VehicleArr)
        If VehicleArr(y) < VehicleArr(x) Then
            VehicleTmp = VehicleArr(y)
            VehicleArr(y) = VehicleArr(x)
            VehicleArr(x) = VehicleTmp
        End If
    Next y
Next x

' now the "fun" part >> paste to "Sheet2"
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Value = "ADDRESS"
    .Range("B4").Value = FilterVal
    .Range("C1").Value = "VEHICLE(S) USED"

    ' clear contents from previous run

    .Range("B50:B55").ClearContents
    .Range("B50:B" & UBound(VehicleArr) + 49) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VehicleArr)

End With

FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

I have found that if I enter an address it will give me the desired output. If I edit B4 to change the address to another, it also works. However, when I delete cell B4, I get a message that says "Runtime error 13 Type Mismatch.

When I Debug, it brings me to the line

```
 Call FilterAddress(Target.Value)
```

How can I change the code so that when cell B4 is deleted, no action is taken and a message appears asking the user to enter an address?

Comment: You need to test whether `Target` contains more than one cell, and also test whether it contains an error.

Comment: As I understand error 13, it usually means a variant subtype does not match the object you are trying to assign it to. In this case, your FilterAddress routine is asking for a string, so maybe you just need to use `Call FilterAddress(CStr(Target.Value))`--just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this to include an additional check for B4's value should be enough.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        If (Target.Value <> "") Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call FilterAddress(Target.Value)
        Else
            MsgBox Target.Address & " can't be blank, Input a value first."
        End If
    End If
```

---

Just in case you like to do things in the detailed way ....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strErr As String

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsTargetValid(Target, strErr) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call FilterAddress(Target.Value)
        Else
            MsgBox strErr
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function IsTargetValid(rng As Range, ByRef strErr As String) As Boolean

    Dim bResult As Boolean

    bResult = True
    If bResult And IsError(rng) Then
        bResult = False
        strErr = rng.Address & " contains error value."
    End If

    If bResult And rng.Cells.Count <> 1 Then
        bResult = False
        strErr = rng.Address & " contains invalid number of cells."
    End If

    If bResult And rng <> "" Then
        bResult = False
        strErr = rng.Address & " can't be blank, input a value first."
    End If

    '// Keep adding any other condition you want to check.

    IsTargetValid = bResult

End Function
```

Comment: Your first box works but it is ignoring the MsgBox you provided, and giving me the MsgBox i have MsgBox "The address you entered is incorrect. Please try again." I have updated my code – Phil S. 16 mins ago

Comment: The second box does not work, because even when I enter values that work, I am getting messages saying `$B$4 contains error value`

Answer (score 0):

actually your `Worksheet_Change()` event handler works for me: if I delete cell B4, I just get the *"The Appointment # you entered is incorrect or does not exist. Please try again"* message. Which is fine.

maybe refactoring your code could help you debugging it

for instance you could

- demand array ordering to a specific Sub like the following:

  ```
  Sub OrderArray(arrayToOrder As Variant)
      Dim ServiceTmp As Variant
      Dim iRow As Long, iRow2 As Long

      ' Bubble-sort Service Array >> sorts the passed array from smallest to largest
      For iRow = LBound(arrayToOrder) To UBound(arrayToOrder) - 1
          For iRow2 = iRow + 1 To UBound(arrayToOrder)
              If arrayToOrder(iRow2) < arrayToOrder(iRow) Then
                  ServiceTmp = arrayToOrder(iRow2)
                  arrayToOrder(iRow2) = arrayToOrder(iRow)
                  arrayToOrder(iRow) = ServiceTmp
              End If
          Next
      Next
  End Sub
  ```
- demand the getting of unique and ordered values out of a range to a Function like the following

  ```
  Function GetOrderedUniqueValuesArrayFromRange(filteredRng As Range) As Variant
      Dim cell As Range
      Dim arr As Variant
      Dim iArr As Variant

      With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '<--| create a late binded 'Dictionary' object "on the fly" - no need for adding any library references to the project
          For Each cell In filteredRng
              ' read values from cell to array using the Split function
              arr = Split(cell.value, ",")
              For iArr = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                  arr(iArr) = Trim(arr(iArr)) ' remove extra spaces from string
                  .item(arr(iArr)) = .item(arr(iArr)) + 1
              Next
          Next cell
          GetOrderedUniqueValuesArrayFromRange = .Keys '<--| the dictionary keys is the wanted array, though not ordered
          OrderArray GetOrderedUniqueValuesArrayFromRange '<--| order it
      End With '<--| release the no more necessary 'Dictionary' object
  End Function
  ```
- then you can *collapse* your `FilterAddress()` sub code as follows:

  ```
  Sub FilterAddress(FilterVal As String)
      Dim FilterRng As Range
      Dim VehicleArr As Variant
      Dim ServiceArr As Variant

      With Sheets("Sheet1") '<--| reference your "data" sheet
          With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:C cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one
              .AutoFilter '<--| remove any previuous filter
              .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterVal 'filter referenced range on its 1st column with 'FilterVal' value
              With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered cells skipping header row
                  ServiceArr = GetOrderedUniqueValuesArrayFromRange(Intersect(.Cells, .Columns(2).EntireColumn)) '<--| fill ServiceArr with unique ordered values from 2nd column of referenced range
                  VehicleArr = GetOrderedUniqueValuesArrayFromRange(Intersect(.Cells, .Columns(3).EntireColumn)) '<--| fill VehicleArr with unique ordered values from 3nd column of referenced range
              End With
          End With
          .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
      End With

      ' now the "fun" part >> paste to "Sheet2"
      With Sheets("Sheet2")
          .Range("A1").value = "ADDRESS"
          .Range("B4").value = FilterVal
          .Range("C1").value = "VEHICLE(S) USED"

          .Range("B12:B17").ClearContents ' clear service contents from previous run
          .Range("B12").Resize(UBound(ServiceArr) - LBound(ServiceArr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ServiceArr)

          .Range("B50:B55").ClearContents ' clear vehicle contents from previous run
          .Range("B50").Resize(UBound(VehicleArr) - LBound(VehicleArr) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VehicleArr)
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

hope this could help you

let me know if you will